# How to get the name of the application that generated the drag and drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

How do I find out which application dropped some content on my C# form?

Right now I'm doing some wild guesses, like

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UniformResourceLocatorW", true)) {
  // URL dropped from IExplorer
}
```

But what I'm really looking for is something like:

```
if (isDroppedFrom("iexplorer")) {
  // URL dropped from IExplorer
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Good question, also, if anyone knows the opposite of this (how to get the drop location of the dragged item from the created application), could they also share :-)

Comment: For the vice-versa case, I think you could probably just detect where the user let go of the mouse and then use window-handle-to-PID logic to figure it out. It'd be a bit of a hack, but it's an easier problem.

Comment: for html stuff, it can be found in the SourceURL "item":

    String pastedHtml = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html);

    Version:1.0
    StartHTML:000000182
    EndHTML:000008325
    StartFragment:000008144
    EndFragment:000008205
    StartSelection:000008144
    EndSelection:000008205
    SourceURL:http://www.msn.com/
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
    "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

    <HTML lang=en-us xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, this is what I ended up doing, for those interested...

```
// Firefox //
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("text/x-moz-url", true)) {
    HandleFirefoxUrl(e);
} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("text/_moz_htmlcontext", true)) {
    HandleFirefoxSnippet(e);

// Internet Explorer //
} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UntrustedDragDrop", false)) {
    HandleIELink(e);
} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UniformResourceLocatorW", false)) {
    HandleIEPage(e);

} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true)) { //FILES
    Array droppedFiles = (Array)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    HandleFiles(droppedFiles);

} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap, true)) { // BITMAP
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    HandleBitmap(image);

} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Html, true)) { // HTML
    String pastedHtml = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
    HandleHtml(pastedHtml);

} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, true)) { // CSV
    MemoryStream memstr = (MemoryStream)e.Data.GetData("Csv");
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(memstr);
    String pastedCSV = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
    HandleCSV(pastedCSV);

    //  } else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Tiff, true)) {
    //  } else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.WaveAudio, true)) {

} else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text, true)) { //TEXT
    String droppedText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    HandleText(droppedText);

[else if .....]

} else { // UNKNOWN
    Debug.WriteLine("unknown dropped format");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no direct information in the drag drop structure that indicates the originating application.

See *[Shell Clipboard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902(VS.85).aspx) (MSDN).

If you're only interested in finding out if it's a drop from Internet Explorer, the presence of CFSTR_UNTRUSTEDDRAGDROP is a clue; AFAIK, only Internet Explorer and Web Browser Controls will put this format on the clipboard.

Comment: thanks Eric, sounds good. still, i need to differentiate btw all major app type (ffox, ie, word, excel, email, ...). so right now i'm making my way through by sniffing some hints like UniformResourceLocatorW and the like, but i was hoping for a more generic and solid approach...